# Wordpress php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure , but other attempts to connect with mysql work fine

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, php-5.6

I get the following message when I access a wordpress server hosted on EC2 with a security group that has access to the RDS instance.

Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in [...]/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in [...]/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1562

Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in [...]/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1562

Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in[...]/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1562

If I create a test file using the same login info but mysqli instead of wordpress to connect I get a successful connection, similarly, using the same login info but with the mysql cli tool, I get a successful connection.

```
<?
$mysqli = new mysqli("xxx.cluster-xxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com", "root", "xxx", "dbname");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
?>
```

Looking for guidance as to why the mysql connection through wordpress fails like this when other attempts to connect using the same info do not.

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out? Also, was the error consistent or transient? Thanks!

Comment: I never figured it out, consistent. @Erebus